# List of 50 random numbers in csh

Tags: shell, unix, csh, tcsh

I want to create a list or array of 50 random numbers in csh.

Here is what I tried:

```
@ i=0
set x
While ($i<50)
X[$i]= `perl -e 'srand; print int(rand(200)+1)'`
@ i++
end
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: please include, (in the question proper), your evidence that "it doesn't work". It looks very close to working. Did you turn on the csh debugging with `#!/bin/csh -vx` at the top. Then you can see each line as it will be executed AND ALSO each line with all variable values substituted in place. (AND be warned, long-term programming csh leads to blindness. See http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-0 . Better to spend your time in a shell (ksh or bash, others, I'm sure) that theirs own $RANDOM variable.  Good luck.

Comment: While IMO t/csh is an awesome interactive shell, it is considered very [bad for scripting](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) and strongly discauraged. Consider using another language.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
repeat 50 perl -e 'print int(rand() * 200) . "\n";'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk (assuming you want 50 random integers between 0 and 200):

```
echo 1 | awk '{for(i=1;i<=50;i++) print int(201*rand())}'
```

or perhaps simpler:

```
repeat 50 echo 1 | awk '{print int(201*rand())}'
```